# Custom Binding Calling Only Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

After this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339870/dynamically-accessing-properties-of-knockoutjs-observable-array/16340654?noredirect=1#16340654), knockoutjs custom binding is working, but the update function is working only once on clicking the same column again. How to make call the function again ?

After googling i found

```
ko.cleanNode(element)
```

How to apply this? Any ideas?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nHthh/2/)

Comment: What do you mean on: "the update function is working only once on clicking the same column again"? What should happen when you click for the second time?

Comment: I updated my question with fiddle, onclicking the username column, the column is getting sorted by descending, and on clicking it again it is not at all sorting. But i want it to sort again by ascending. Hope you understands...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the state of last sorBy and if it matches then flip sort direction.

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tkirda/nHthh/4/

```
var lastSortBy = '';
var direction = 1;

ko.bindingHandlers.sortFunction = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var sortBy = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var items = viewModel.items;
        $(element).unbind('click.sort').bind('click.sort', function() {
            if (lastSortBy === sortBy){
                direction = direction === 1 ? -1 : 1;
            } else {
                direction = 1;
            }
            lastSortBy = sortBy;
            items.sort(function(a, b) {
                return direction * (a[sortBy]() < b[sortBy]() ? -1 : 1);
            });
        });
    }
}
```